# Aerospike not starting automatically after system reboot

Tags: linux, database, startup, systemd, aerospike

I am running aerospike and other services , manual setup is working fine and when I tried to add all the other services as systemd services in my Linux environment , as the processes can start soon after reboot. All services are starting up except aerospike. I have followed [this](https://www.aerospike.com/docs/operations/manage/aerospike/systemd/index.html) documentation and I can only manually start after reboot. What else to be done to make it up soon after reboot ?

I have installed aerospike following [this](https://www.aerospike.com/docs/operations/install/linux/el6) documentation.

Attached the log screenshot.
[image]

Command used to check the status after reboot is below :

> sudo systemctl status aerospike

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: This question came as part of my programming/development only. And I can see programmers/developers out there here can answer this. Thanks for the suggestion by the way .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried enabling the service unit?

```
systemctl enable aerospike
```